# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor add tasks upon available active threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to call a REST service asynchronously using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. I have to call the same service asynchronously for the given input. I have a thread pool of a certain size and want to send a request to the service once the active thread count is less than the pool size. I am not sure how I could do that.  Here is the sample code.

```
public class CallableWrkr implements Callable<Response>{

    public CallableWrkr(Map<String,String> headers,
             String hostName,  Transfer transfer, String name) {
        this.transfer = transfer;
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Response call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(name + 1);
         Thread.sleep((new Random().nextInt(5000)) + 500);
        CoreServicesImpl service = new CoreServicesImpl();
        service.setHost(hostName);

        Response resp = service.process( headers,
                   transfer);
        System.out.println(name + 2);
        return resp;
    }

}
```

I want to do some thing like below when I have a list of transfer objects.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) context.getBean("taskExecutor");

for (;;) {
            int count = taskExecutor.getActiveCount();
            System.out.println("Active Threads : " + count);
            if(count < taskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize())
            {
                CallableWrkr callableTask = new CallableWrkr(headers transfers.get(i), new Integer(threadNumber).toString());
                Future<Response> result = taskExecutor.submit(callableTask);

                futureList.add(result);
            }
            else {
                wait();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                taskExecutor.shutdown();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Not sure if I could do that. Is there a queue I can add the list to?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear who's adding tasks to the taskExecutor, nor who is calling your callableTask. In any case, I think you should look into using the beforeExecute or afterExecute methods from the ThreadPoolExecutor: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: Hi Alejandro C, sorry I missed that in the code snippet. taskExecutor.submit(callableTask);   submits the callableTask.